# Univalent functions with non-negative coefficients

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-functions

> Is anything non-trivial known about univalent functions with non-negative coefficients?

Let $U$ be the unit disc, and $f$ a univalent (=injective) holomorphic function, $f(0)=0$,
$f'(0)>0$. There is a one-to-one correspondence between such functions and simply connected regions
$D$ in the plane, containing $0$. The function is real iff $D$ is symmetric with respect to the real
line.

1. What can be said about $D$ if it is known that coefficients are non-negative?
   (Except the trivial fact that the boundary point of the largest modulus is on the positive ray).
2. What can be said about non-negative coefficients of a power series if it is known that it
   represents a univalent function?
3. Is it possible to parametrize this class?

I am especially interested in the case when the positive ray is contained in $D$, that is $f(1)=\infty$.